# MySQL/PHP checking active relations

Tags: mysql, relationship, database-relations

I have 2 big tables and i need to check how many relations between them are still active.
The first table is a relations table with around 100k rows in it (ID, ID_something1, ID_something2 ). The second table is a bit larger, with around 6 mil entries with ties to specific relations. Over time some of the relations got deleted, but the data still remained. Now I am curious how much of the data is still in tact.

So I wrote something like:

```
SELECT count(tab_data.id) 
FROM tab_data, tab_rel
WHERE tab_data.id_rel = tab_rel.id
```

and i got a nice (believable) answer in less then a seconds.

Then i started to question the accuracy of the upper WHERE clause and rewrote it to something that should give me exactly what need. So i ended up with this:

```
SELECT count(tab_data.id) 
FROM tab_data, tab_rel
WHERE tab_data.id_rel IN 
(SELECT ID FROM tab_rel)
```

To make the story short(er), after half an hour of CPU-torment, I killed off the MySQL server and restarted it :S Since then I read that there are (or were) problems with WHERE IN clauses in MySQL, so I guess I'm not trying that one again.

IMO those two queries should be the same, but i need to be 100% sure. So all i really need is, for someone to confirm my hunch and tell me something in the lines of: "don't worry, those 2 DO give the same result!"

While we're at it... The table is just called a relations table, because that's what I use it for. But i don't have any foreign keys set up. Would i gain anything time related by adding those or would i have to re-code somethings as well? (I'll probably research that, before i read your answer, but since you already read all of this, you can throw in your 2 cents :D )

Comment: What means "in tact"? What do you want to do?

Comment: Check how many of the tab_data.id_rel still exist as tab_rel.id

Comment: To make it clearer: I know that in the table "tab_rel", the row with ID = 1 has been deleted. I also know that there are 10 rows with id_rel = 1 in tab_data, that are useless at this point, since its relation has been deleted. I want to count all of the useless data or all of the useful (in tact!!!) data. (i'm asking about the later in the upper post)